# .htaccess ignore folder names

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to use `.htaccess` to make clean url's but I'm having troubles with the folder names.

I want something like:

```
mydomain.com/test
```

redirecting to:
`mydomain.com/?p=test` but maitaining the clean url `mydomain.com/test`

And it works just fine, the problem is when I try to redirect a name that is the same name of a folder for exemple if `test` is a folder name, when I redirect it works but the url will be something like `mydomain.com/test/?p=test` insted of `mydomain/test`

I've tried a lot of config and none of them work, currently my `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ ?p=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `RewriteRule ^(.*?\.php)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.+)? $1$4?$2=$3 [NC,N,QSA]`
This checks for file extension.